# Products in $Set$ category.

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra

1. I want to prove that products over small set $J$ exist in $Set$(category of all small sets).
2. My question :
   how to prove the Cartesian product $\prod_{i \in I}x_i $ with $x_i$ and $I$small sets is a small set?
3. My thinking:
   I need to use the definition of set by universe. But I find two different definitions and I can't prove they are equivalent.one is Mac Lane's book:[image: $def$ A]
   $def A$

Another is Hankbook of Categorical Algebra 1[image: $def$ B]$def B$

I can prove if we have $def B$,then we can get $def A$.I can't prove the inverse.
And I can prove if we have $def B$,then the Cartesian product $\prod_{i\in I} x_i $ with $x_i$ and $I$ small sets is a small set.

I am looking forward to your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only question is how to prove (2).

Given $I\in \mathcal{U}$ and $\forall i\in I.x_i\in \mathcal{U}$, we can make a function $x : I \to \bigcup_{i\in I}\{x_i\}$ via $x(i) = \{x_i\}$. $x$ is surjective and $\bigcup_{i\in I}\{x_i\} \subseteq \mathcal{U}$. Thus, by (v), $\bigcup_{i\in I}\{x_i\}\in\mathcal{U}$. By (iii), $\bigcup\bigcup_{i\in I}\{x_i\} = \bigcup_{i\in I}\bigcup\{x_i\} = \bigcup_{i\in I}x_i \in \mathcal{U}$.

Comment: thank you. It seems that the universe in category is complicated.I have some trouble to understand it.I do not see the intrinsic meaning

Comment: @Sky If you compare the definition of universe to the [axioms of ZF set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory#Axioms), you see a universe is basically a model of ZF within the ambient set theory. Extensionality, foundation, and separation are "inherited" from the ambient set theory. Clearly $U$ can't exist in ZF because that would let it prove its own consistency, and sure enough the existence of $U$ is [unprovable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grothendieck_universe) in ZF. $U$ is the *set* of objects for the category of small sets.